# Rotation and relativity

Tags: rotation, general-relativity

When a planet is spinning around its own axis, it has an effect on the trajectory of its satellites. I believe it is called frame dragging.

Spin increases the kinetic energy of an object, contributing to its mass-energy, but some other effect must come into play as well.

How does one differentiate between spin and orbit velocity?

What is the *effect* of the spin? Lets say that Earth suddenly started spinning faster, what would happen to the moons trajectory?

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted? I just want to know what the *observed* physical effect of various rates of spin would be, and what causes it.

Comment: I'd recommend reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame-dragging, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lense%E2%80%93Thirring_effect, and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric

Comment: It isn't actually clear what question you are asking. Are you asking what causes frame-dragging? ('...but some other effect must come into play...'). Are you asking how to differentiate between spin and orbit velocities? Are you asking what the observable effects are if a body had a different rate of spin?

Answer (score 1):

The moon's rotation plane would precess (more) in the same direction as Earth's rotation, if the Earth spun faster.

Comment: Is the increased precession the only result of increased mass (due to higher kinetic energy)?

Comment: So, an object that is spinning does not have a higher kinetic energy? And through E=mc^2 you don't get an increase in mass-energy as a result of spin? I will accept your answer if you answer that by editing your answer. :)

Comment: While the answer does not claim to state that this is the only effect, which I would rely on others to comment on (eg Moon's trajectory, what else besides increased mass contributes to frame-dragging), the answer, I think, stands as an answer to the question about what happens if the Earth spun faster.